# Rails Test post Request with firefox plugin results in bad request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, post

I m trying to test the create method of my rails App , I cant figure out what is wrong and why constantly having "bad request".

The routing goes line this:

```
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :routes
      resources :line_items
end
```

end

My controller is like this:

def create
    @route = Route.new(permitted_params)

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @route.save
    format.json { render json: @route, status: :created }
  else
    format.json { render json: @route.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

My permitted params are these:

```
  def permitted_params
    params.require(:route).permit(:comment)
  end
```

I use the firefox plugin OpenHttpRequester and this is what I get when I click to POST button, when I insert submit my `json` = `route:{comment:"bla"}`
Any ideas what of what the request should be ?

I have changed the json part to `{"route":{"comment":"bla"}` and get a nice 422 response.. still no luck

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the following line in the controller:

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
```